# What Can I use instead of KeyChar?

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Module Functions
    Public Function intError()
        Dim e As System.EventArgs
        If AscW(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or AscW(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
            MessageBox.Show("You can only enter numbers.", " You did wrong, Honey!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Using e.KeyChar is not working as it requires KeyPressEventArgs and as it's function in this module, I can't KeyPress event here for it. So I need something that can be used instead of KeyChar.

Comment: KeyChar is not working because it does not exist on the object correct ?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: How is this function supposed to know what key has been pressed? The caller must pass `e` or better `e.KeyChar` to the function.

Comment: A keystroke generates an event, and the handler for that event receives `KeyPressEventArgs` (thus the word `Event` in the name). How is `intError` supposed to know what key was pressed at all? You can't just invent a keystroke out of nowhere, which is what your code is trying to do now.

Comment: Then It will be called by TextBox_keypress and I want the TextBox to not get characters except numbers but I have a lot of textboxes thats why I brought it in module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't KeyPress event here for it. So I need something that can be used instead of KeyChar.

Can't see why you can't use the KeyPress event handler for a TextBox, cause that will do what you want.  To add the same handler to different controls you can use a For Each loop in the Form load handler.  If necessary the event handler can be in the Public Module, if you want events on controls on different forms to be handled with it.

If you change your function to accept a Char and return a boolean you could accomplish what you want quite simply by using the Char.IsDigit method.  And convert the e argument in the event handler to Char.  Something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        AddHandler tb.KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_KeyPress
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    e.Handled = intError(e.KeyChar)
End Sub

Public Function intError(Character As Char) As Boolean
    intError = False
    If Not Char.IsDigit(Character) Then
        intError = True
        MessageBox.Show("You can only enter numbers.", " You did wrong, Honey!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The way you posted worked thanks but it effects to all the TextBox because of the for loop you added in Form1. Could you plz tell me how can I do this way to only specific TextBoxes not all of them?

Comment: If you name the textboxes in specific manner(tb1,tb2,tb3,etc.) you can use an If statement to see if the name contains a specific string(`If tb.Name.Contains("tb") Then`), to restrict which textboxes use that handler.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in the New Sub `Me.KeyPreview = True`

With that you can handle the KeyEventArgs

```
Private Sub KeyPressed(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.D1
            ' Do Stuff
        ...
        Else Case
            'Other stuff
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to put it in a module u can put the event under one textbox and specify that that textbox handles other textbox's eg if u have two textboxes one named txtStudentNumber and txtPhoneNumber you can write 
`Private Sub txtStudentNumber_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtStudentNumber.KeyPress, txtPhoneNumber.KeyPress` 
notice how after Handles you can specify which other textbox's events u can control. Then within the sub u can use the code
`If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then`
`'only numbers entered`
            `e.Handled = True`
            `Beep() 'play beeping sound`
        `End If`

Holla if it works...n give a boy some votes plz